# How to AWX launch Job ID of a Scheduled Job

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

When i schedule job in AWX i get schedule job id (for example - 343), After the job launched on scheduled time, i get new launch job id(for example - 34848) that is different from schedule job id.

How to get job id of launch job based on schedule job id.

Example - I want to pull 34848 job using schedule job id 343.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can able to get launch job ID using schedule job ID

Using below API filter:

```
https://{{awx_url}}/api/v2/job_templates/{{ job template id }}/jobs/?schedule__id={{ schedule job id }}
```

And if i want to get Launch Job based on schedule name

```
https://{{awx_url}}/api/v2/job_templates/{{ job template id }}/jobs/?schedule__name={{ schedule job name }}
```